# multilevel dropdown menu blinking in html

Tags: html, menu, header, drop-down-menu, submenu

anyone please tell me what is the problem to load the Product's submenu.

Here is the link:

http://www.lexurcapacitor.com/index.html

This is the css link:

http://www.lexurcapacitor.com/css/style.css

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery 1.5.1 and then 1.6.4?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the menu blinks because of the code in the `<script src="js/dualflow.js"></script>` file;

`c("#header-nav").delegate("li","mouseenter mouseleave",function(f){`

This code executed when there is a mouseenter or mouseleave event fires on the **li** element inside the `<nav id="header-nav">`. The drawback with this code is that, it considers the **li** inside the submenu also!

The easiest solution I got is to have a class for the **li** element of first menu items(*eg: Home, About, Products...*)

**HTML UPDATE**

```
<nav id="header-nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="current menu">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>                       
            <li class="menu">
                <a href="msc.html">Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="msc.html">Motor Start Capacitor</a>
                        </li>   
                        <li>
                            <a href="mrc.html">Motor Run Capacitor</a>
                        </li>   
                        <li>
                            <a href="tc.html">Terminal Capacitor</a>
                        </li>   
                        <li>
                            <a href="bstc.html">Box Square Type Capacitor</a>
                        </li>   
                        <li>
                            <a href="flc.html">Fluorescent Lighting Capacitor</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="fc.html">Fan Capacitor</a>
                        </li>                   
                    </ul>
                </li>  
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="needus.html">Need us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="network.html">Network</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="certificate.html">Certificates</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu">
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

**dualflow.js UPDATE**

Update the dualflow.js file with following code(add class 'menu')

<strike>`c("#header-nav").delegate("li","mouseenter mouseleave",function(f){`</strike>

```
c("#header-nav").delegate("li.menu","mouseenter mouseleave",function(f){
```